# How to select data based on what a user has access to using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm using code-first Entity Framework, and I've created all of the models (Category, Data, UserData) and let EF create all of the tables. So, my database currently looks like this:

[image: Relationship of tables]

I've managed to get the "self relationship" sorted with the category table, and I've managed to also link in the "data" table. EF quite happily pulls out all of the categories for a given parent, along with the associated "data" items.

The bit I'm stuck on is; only grabbing the "data" items in a category for which the user has "access" to. So the idea is a user can create "data" items in a category, and then give permission as to who can view them. Here's the code listing for my models:

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public Int32? Category_ParentID { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Category Parent_Category { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Data> Datas { get; set; }
    public Int16 CategoryOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

[Table("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 DataId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public Int32 Parent_CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

}

[Table("UserData")]
public class UserData
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public Int32 DataId { get; set; }
    public Data UsersData { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser UserDataUser { get; set; }
}
```

And in the database context class I have the mappings for category->category and category->data:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Parent_Category)
            .WithMany(b => b.SubCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.Category_ParentID) // FK_Category_ParentID
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Parent)
            .WithMany(b => b.Datas)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.Parent_CategoryId) // FK_Parent_CategoryId
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

**More Info**

I'm trying to retreive a list of categories, including the associated the "data" items, that the user has "access" to:

```
            //return the selected item - with its children
            var selectedCategoryItem = DatabaseContext.Categories
                    .ToList().Select(c => new Category()
                    {
                        SubCategories = c.SubCategories.Where(sub => !sub.Deleted).ToList(),    //make sure only undeleted subcategories are returned
                        CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                        CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                        Category_ParentID = c.Category_ParentID,
                        CategoryOrder = c.CategoryOrder,
                        Parent_Category = c.Parent_Category,
                        Datas = c.Datas.Where(d => !d.Deleted).ToList(),          //make sure only undeleted Datas are returned
                        Deleted = c.Deleted
                    })
                    .Single(c => c.CategoryId == ParentCategoryId);
```

The above code currently grabs a specified parent category, with its associates sub categories and "data" items - I need to filter out the "data" items the user doesnt have access to.

Comment: What do you want to return? List of categories? List of Datas? Please provide the sample code that you have tried so we know where to fix.

Comment: I've added more into to my question.

Comment: You have `ToList` in the beginning of the query, that will execute all categories from the database, are you planning to do the filter as objects instead of sql?

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd write a stored procedure or a LINQ query... but I'm just trying to get to grips with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this filter.

```
var userId = ..; // provides the user id
Datas = c.Datas.Where(d => 
    !d.Deleted 
    && DatabaseContext.UserDatas.Any(ud => 
        ud.DataId == d.DataId && ud.Id == userId).ToList()
)
```

Comment: The AsEnumerable() didn't work, but pretty much everything else did.

Comment: @binks, the lazy loading needs to be disabled during the query until all values are retrieved if you want to use second option

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, I always get the error: The entity or complex type 'Category' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @binks, I removed the second option, probably I'm missing something when converting the query